# kivy Config.get results in NoSecionError

Tags: python, kivy

I try to set some config attributes with an customm section. Then when I want to read the attributes I get an `NoSectionError`. The example below is absolute basic and may don't make sense in this way. But I need to read the config in the `build` method.

Versions used:

- Python 2.7
- kivy 1.9.1

Example

```
class MyTestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Config.get('user_settings', 'strategy1')
        return FloatLayout()

    def build_config(self, config):
        config.setdefaults('user_settings',
                           {
                               'strategy1': 'example',
                               'strategy2': 'example'
                           })

MyTestApp().run()
```

Result in the following exception:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "test/main.py", line 59, in <module>
     MyTestApp().run()
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 802, in run
     root = self.build()
   File "test/main.py", line 17, in build
     Config.get('user_settings', 'strategy1')
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\config.py", line 433, in get
     value = PythonConfigParser.get(self, section, option, **kwargs)
   File "C:\Python27\lib\ConfigParser.py", line 607, in get
     raise NoSectionError(section)
 ConfigParser.NoSectionError: No section: 'user_settings'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the app you'll have to use `self.config` instead of `Config`